# How to fit large text in AG-Grid Header?

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid

I set `.ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {white-space:break-spaces !important;}` in order to see the full text when width is not enough.But when text is very long like below

```
headerName: 'Age of Athlete and asdadfsdf fgdsfgdsfg sdfgsdfgsdfg',
```

[image]

you can see that it doesn't fit.I increased the height of row but nothing changed.How can I fit long text doesnt matter how much long it is?

Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/UtfwvTOhpRDivBu5

Comment: You will have to make text smaller or make cell bigger.

Comment: Do you need the max-width property set for the age field? When it is removed Auto-Size All is behaving as you expected

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this `headerHeight : 150` inside `gridOptions` to increase the header height if the header text is too long. Because adding this line`.ag-header-cell-label .ag-header-cell-text {white-space:break-spaces !important;}` you will only get the text in multiple lines with the previous height. Try it and if it won't work comment here again.

Comment: For this headerHeight property,I need something dynamic.Because if I set 150 it wont be proper solution if text changes and gets longer

Comment: Okay so you need to add some property that is dynamic with your header text. Gotcha !!